# Why image from blob field displays only once?

Tags: doctrine, blob, fosuserbundle, symfony

I overrided FOSUserBundle.
I changed my avatar field getter and setter in user Entity (This Entity extends FOSUser Entity) to this:

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="blob")
*/
protected $avatar;

public function setAvatar($avatar) {
    if ($avatar != null) {
        $strm = fopen($avatar->getRealPath(), 'rb');
        $this->avatar = stream_get_contents($strm);
    }
    return $this;
}

public function getAvatar() {
    if ($this->avatar != null) {
        return base64_encode(stream_get_contents($this->avatar));
    } else {
        return $this->avatar;
    }
}
```

And it works but only in first render

```
<img alt="User avatar" src="data:image;base64,{{app.user.avatar}}"/> //working
<img alt="User avatar" src="data:image;base64,{{app.user.avatar}}"/> //not working
```

If i try display this field first time all is ok and each next render shows empty string. Why? How fix this?

Other fields works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine will not use your setters to populate your entity when it is loaded from the database. Thus, when you first call `getAvatar()`, `stream_get_contents()` is executed and reads everything from the stream. The next time this getter method is called, there is nothing left to read from the stream. You will probably want to save the string returned by `stream_get_contents()` in the `$avatar` property when `getAvatar()` is called like you do in `setAvatar()`.

Comment: You have right. I solved my problem by adding two parameters to function `stream_get_contents($this->avatar, -1, 0)`  `-1` mean read all the remaining buffer and `0` is offset