# stream_get_contents in loop work half the time

Tags: image, symfony

In my controller I retrieve several boxes, and for the images of each box I do like this because I have the images in a blob column:

```
  $donnees = $entityManager
->getRepository(Occasion::class)
->findBy(['isOnLine' => true], ['id' => "DESC"]);

$occasions = $paginator->paginate(
    $donnees, /* query NOT result */
    $request->query->getInt('page', 1), /*page number*/
    12 /*limit per page*/
);



//on va stocker les images
$images = [];
foreach($occasions as $key => $occasion) {
    $images[$key] = stream_get_contents($occasion->getBoite()->getImageBlob());
}
```

But when I dump $images I only have 1 image out of 2...

```
CataloguesController.php on line 137:
array:4 [▼
  0 => "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAIBAQIBAQICAgICAgICAwUDAwMDAwYEBAMFBwYHBwcGBwcICQsJCAgKCAcHCg0KCgsMDAwMBwkODw0MDgsMDAz/2wBDAQICAgMDAwYDAwYMCAcIDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwM ▶"
  1 => ""
  2 => "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAeAB4AAD/2wBDAAIBAQIBAQICAgICAgICAwUDAwMDAwYEBAMFBwYHBwcGBwcICQsJCAgKCAcHCg0KCgsMDAwMBwkODw0MDgsMDAz/2wBDAQICAgMDAwYDAwYMCAcIDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwM ▶"
  3 => ""
]
```

Do you know why ? Thanks

???

Comment: ??? Nobody can help me ?

Comment: RÉSOLU !!!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34634882/why-image-from-blob-field-displays-only-once

stream_get_contents($this->imageBlob, -1, 0)